# CakePHP 2.x - How to insert a new manually created record

Tags: model, cakephp-2.0

The below function from my model **updates** an existing record **instead of creating a new one**. I am **not specifying the new primary key value** in the `$data` variable and was hoping to avoid specifying it.

```
public function add( $prop1, $prop2 ) 
    {           
        $this->create();
        $data = array
        (
            'Model' => array
            (
                'prop1' => $prop1,
                'prop2' => $prop2
            )
        );
        $this->save( $data );
    } // add
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Best idea:

```
$this->create();
$this->save(array('prop1' => $prop1, 'prop2' => $prop2));
```

Don't do:

```
 $this->create();
```

This's help your work code, in your Model Cakephp 2:

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default'); 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'); 
$_result = $db->create($Order, array('accountant', 'name','address_payment','account_id', 'order_type', 'order_code', 'order_datetime', 'order_status', 'no_more_email'), 
    array($_name_acc, $_name_acc, $_address_acc, $_acc_id, '1', CakeSession::read('order_code'), date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), '3', '1') 
); 
$_new_order_id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 0):

//    Cake 2.x

```
$this->Model->create();
$this->Model->save($data);
```

I like the way you have defined $data, looks AOK.

=========================EDIT==========================

Jeez, I'm an idiot. You said model in the first sentence.

Don't use 'model' => array(

take that layer out of $data and it should work in the model.

Also, you are correct, in the model.php file, you should not say

```
$this->model->save($data);
```

instead just say

```
$this->save($data);
```

just tested below and it worked for me.

```
public function add_from_model( $prop1, $prop2 ) {
$this->create();
$this->save(array('prop1' => $prop1, 'prop2' => $prop2));
}
```

(changed the name of the model function, don't know if I had to do that)

Comment: I have this function in the **model**, not the controller. If I am correct (and may not be, am away from my work PC), it should suffice to use `$this->create()` instead of `$this->Model->create()` in the structures in my Model. Anyhow, thanks for the suggestion. I will try your suggestion tomorrow and let you know if it worked.

Comment: As expected, I received a `Error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object`

Answer (score 0):

Times come when it is cheaper to come up with a workaround.

```
private function getNextPrimaryId()
{
    $result = $this->query
    (
        "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'models';"
    );
    $next = $result[0]['TABLES']['Auto_increment'];
    return $next;
} // getNextPrimaryId

public function add( $prop1, $prop2 )
{
    $data = array
    (
        'Model' => array
        (
            'model_primary_id' => $this->getNextPrimaryId(),
            'prop1' => $prop1,
            'prop2' => $prop2
        )
    );
    $this->create();
    $this->save( $data );
} // add
```

Comment: That is awful. If save only updates you have a significant problem (probably with other code that's in the model - unclear because the code in the question _does not_ do what you say on its own). Doing what's in this answer just leaves you to find whatever that problem is in the future.

Comment: I understand this - but these are the only two functions I have in the mode :-/

Will try to find it in free time tough